# Error TS1086:An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context

Tags: angular

I have this problem and i can't find the solution. Any thoughts?
Since I installed npm ionic2-calendar, start to have this problem. I've tried everything, reinstalling it, updating typescript, angular/cli, angular/core. I just don't figure it out.

`ERROR in node_modules/ionic2-calendar/calendar.d.ts(152,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.`

`node_modules/ionic2-calendar/calendar.d.ts(153,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.`

`node_modules/ionic2-calendar/calendar.service.d.ts(18,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.`

I just can't start my app. Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: check this out https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/9463

Answer (score 0):

**I solved this problem using 0.5.9 version**

```
npm install ionic2-calendar@0.5.9 --save
```